# Inequality $a^ab^bc^c \geq (a+b-c)^a(b+c-a)^b(c+a-b)^c$

Tags: inequality, triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

I found a problem where now I essentially have to show the following inequality
$$a^ab^bc^c \geq (a+b-c)^a(b+c-a)^b(c+a-b)^c$$ where $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle.

I have tried a lot of approaches but am not making headway.

Any hint in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

: Could it be the above inequality is false and what was meant to be proved was what Calvin Lin proved below....If so, can anybody help provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality to be proven is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{a+b-c}{a}\right)^{\frac{a}{a+b+c}}\left(\frac{b+c-a}{b}\right)^{\frac{b}{a+b+c}}\left(\frac{c+a-b}{c}\right)^{\frac{c}{a+b+c}}\leq 1\,.$$
By the Weighted AM-GM Inequality,
$$\begin{align}&\left(\frac{a+b-c}{a}\right)^{\frac{a}{a+b+c}}\left(\frac{b+c-a}{b}\right)^{\frac{b}{a+b+c}}\left(\frac{c+a-b}{c}\right)^{\frac{c}{a+b+c}}\\&\phantom{abcde}\leq \frac{a}{a+b+c}\left(\frac{a+b-c}{a}\right)+\frac{b}{a+b+c}\left(\frac{b+c-a}{b}\right)+\frac{c}{a+b+c}\left(\frac{c+a-b}{c}\right)\,.\end{align}$$
Can you guess what the right-hand side of the inequality above is equal to?

Comment: Ah dang, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Just do the "natural" simplifications.

I'm guessing that you already did the following first step, if you said that you've "tried a lot of approaches".

> Use the substitution of $ a = y+z-x, b = z+x-y, c = x+y-z$, we want to show that
>  $$\prod (\frac{2x} { y+z } ) ^ { y+z } \leq 1. $$

Now, the terms seem complicated because of the mixture of terms, which prevents us from applying Jensen's. However, we can remove that difficulty easily.

> Normalize to $ x + y + z = 1$, and taking log, we want to show that
>  $$ \sum (1-x) \ln ( \frac{ 2x}{ 1-x })  \leq 0 $$

This follows immediately from Jensen's, with equality when $ x  = y = z = \frac{1}{3} $.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and I had done the Ravi's Substitution too but you see the inequality above is different to what you have proved.

Comment: You should mention that the product $P$ changes to $P^k$ if we scale $x,y,z$ by $k,$ we only need to scale by $k > 0,$ and $0 \le x \le 1 \Leftrightarrow 0\le x^k \le 1$ for all $k > 0, x \ge 0.$

Comment: @user35508 Oh oops, I changed the substitution but forgot to update it. Check again.