# Question for Math Olympiad Algebra INDIA PRMO/RMO LEVEL

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Doubt:
$a$,$b$,$c$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that sum of any two of them is greater than the third.

$Prove$ $that$:

$[1-(b-c)\frac 1a ]^a$$[1-(c-a)\frac 1b ]^b$$[1-(a-b)\frac 1c ]^c$$\leq 1$

Thank you.

So it looked like triangular inequality:

What i tried:

$WLG$ $a<b<c$ and then i tried performing triangular inequality or the property that:

$Difference$ $of$ $two$ $sides$ $of$ $a$ $triangle$ $is$ $less$ $than$ $third$ $side$

Issue is:
2 of three terms is less than 1 but one is less than $2^a$. So i was stuck.

Another thing i tried was to take log but i got nowhere too.

Thank you

Comment: This (up to a permutation $(a,b,c)\mapsto(c,b,a)$) answers your question: [Inequality $a^ab^bc^c \geq (a+b-c)^a(b+c-a)^b(c+a-b)^c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640285/inequality-aabbcc-geq-ab-cabc-abca-bc)